# Links won't show in Tumblr's sidebar

Tags: tumblr

I am new to customizing the layout of Tumblr. I am just wondering why my other links won't appear in the sidebar like Vimeo, Archive, etc..

This is the code:

```
 {block:Twitter}<li><a href="http://twitter.com/klydecamilo"><span class="icon twitter"></span><strong>Twitter</strong><br />Follow Me</a></li>{/block:Twitter}


        {block:ifFacebookUrl}<li><a href="{text:https://www.facebook.com/klyde.camilo}"><span class="icon facebook"></span><strong>Facebook</strong><br />Add Me </a></li>{/block:ifFacebookUrl}


        {block:ifFlickrUrl}<li><a href="{text:http://www.flickr.com/}"><span class="icon flickr"></span><strong>Flickr</strong><br />View Photos</a></li>{/block:ifFlickrUrl}


       {block:ifVimeoUrl}<li><a href="{text:http://www.vimeo.com/klydecamilo}"><span class="icon vimeo"></span><strong>Vimeo</strong><br />Watch Videos</a></li>{/block:ifVimeoUrl}

        {block:HasPages}

            {block:Pages}

            <li class="nolabel"><a href="{URL}"><span class="icon page"></span><strong>{Label}</strong></a></li>

            {/block:Pages}

        {/block:HasPages}

        {block:ifContactEmail}<li><a href="mailto:{text:klyde.camilo@gmail.com}"><span class="icon email"></span><strong>Email</strong><br />Send a message</a></li>{/block:ifContactEmail}

        {block:AskEnabled}<li class="nolabel"><a href="/ask"><span class="icon ask"></span><strong>{AskLabel}</strong></a></li>{/block:AskEnabled}

        {block:SubmissionsEnabled}<li class="nolabel"><a href="/submit"><span class="icon submit"></span><strong>{SubmitLabel}</strong></a></li>{/block:SubmissionsEnabled}

        {block:ifShowArchive}<li class="nolabel"><a href="/archive"><span class="icon page"></span><strong>Archive</strong></a></li>{/block:ifShowArchive}
```

[image]

other links should also be seen here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for Archive and Vimeo look correct. That said those tags are custom boolean blocks and require `<meta>` tags in the header. Can you post theses as well to ensure that they're formatted correctly or even included at all.

Although obvious, double check you've actually selected these display options from the Appearance tab in the customization screen.